# Why does PayPal REST API require a Content-Type for content-less (no entity) POST requests?

Tags: paypal

With the PayPal REST API, voiding an authorization only needs to `POST` to `/v1/payments/authorization/<Authorization-Id>/void` without any actual content. As the HTTP entity is empty I was not expecting the `Content-Type` header to be required and set to `application/json`. If I don't set it, my request is rejected. As I'm using Spring's `RestTemplate` with Jackson mapping, providing a `null` request does not set the `Content-Type` and now I'm forced to set it myself.

Do you think this constraint is legitimate or is it a bug?
For me, no body = no content = no content-type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our interest in keeping the `content-type` required on `POST` as a generality is in the interest of future backward compatibility. If we add new media types in the future, we don't want to make assumptions about what your content is (although today it's pretty much application/json). 
In the case of `void`, where there are no fields, there are no guarantees that we wouldn't add fields in the future.

With that in mind: your issue with `RestTemplate` and empty requests in general is interesting, it's something we'll take a closer look at and see if there's something smarter we can do when no fields are specified.